# /proc/XXX/smaps does not exist

Tags: ubuntu, memory

I am trying to debug what is going on on an ubuntu server. I tried to use my good old friend smem but it does not display anything, even if run as root. strace shows the culprit:

```
open("/proc/32376/smaps", O_RDONLY)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I started to scream and kick. Hopefully, the server is not located in my office or it would have suffered some serious damage.

Maybe someone knows why the smaps files do not exist on this box ? (I am running a 2.6.38 kernel on a 64bit box so, it should be here, really)

Mathieu

Comment: Obvious check: is the process ID correct?

Comment: Yes, could it be that PID 32376 is gone in the meantime?

Comment: yes, the pid is correct: this was one of the very many errors I got with strace and I checked that  cat /proc/self/smaps fails too.

Comment: Please identify the specific distribution of Ubuntu.  No issue but I am using a 3.2.0 kernel.  Are you sure it is present in the 2.6.x kernels?

Comment: You might try moving this question to the Ubuntu group.

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment because I just registered my account, but the answer by [@user1979289](https://serverfault.com/a/915411/978937) is correct; not sure why people are downvoting it.

As per the Linux kernel documentation:

```
CONFIG_PROC_PAGE_MONITOR:

Various /proc files exist to monitor process memory utilization:
/proc/pid/smaps, /proc/pid/clear_refs, /proc/pid/pagemap, 
/proc/kpagecount, and /proc/kpageflags. Disabling these interfaces
will reduce the size of the kernel by approximately 4kb.
```

Comment: They are downvoting it because it is a single identifier without any explanations. Yours is better already, because you at least added a documentation entry. You also could have suggested an edit to that answer to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

From the [proc(5) manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/proc.5.html):

> This file is only present if the CONFIG_MMU kernel configuration option is enabled.

Check the kernel configuration to see if this option is enabled (look for a `config-` file in `/boot/` or for `/proc/config.gz`):

```
% grep CONFIG_MMU /boot/config-$(uname -r)\
CONFIG_MMU=y
CONFIG_MMU_NOTIFIER=y
```

Comment: I have `CONFIG_MMU=y` (`zgrep CONFIG_MMU /proc/config.gz`) but still getting the same error - `find /proc -name smaps` finds nothing, and `smem` shows no output. Additional ideas?

Comment: Answering my own question for future readers: My kernel uses [grsecurity patches](http://grsecurity.net/). Grsecurity disables `/proc/<pid>/smaps` for security reasons.

Answer (score -2):

Should enable kernel config:

CONFIG_PROC_PAGE_MONITOR